# Using RestKit to map an NSArray into JSON with dynamic nested attributes?

Tags: objective-c, json, dynamic, nested, restkit

How can I use RestKit to map an NSArray into JSON with dynamic nested attributes?

I have a class which I'll call '`DataModel`', which, along with various other properties, contains the `NSString*` property `DataModel_tag`. I also have a class `UploadObj`, the sole purpose of which is to provide a basis for uploading an array of `DataModel`s. As such, `UploadObj` contains a single property:

```
@property NSMutableArray* DataModels;
```

This needs to be mapped to JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "DataModels" : 
    {
        "DataModel tag 1" : 
            {
                // other properties of DataModel instance 1 here
            },
        "tag for DataModel 2" : 
            {
                // other properties of DataModel instance 2 here
            }
    }
}
```

I'm currently attempting to follow the RestKit object mapping documentation, and have come up with the following methods:

```
+(RKObjectMapping*)mappingForDataModel {

    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:
                                    [DataModel class]];

    [mapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"DataModel_tag"];

    mapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    mapping.rootKeyPath = @"DataModel_tag";

    NSArray* propertyNames = // all properties, names obtained by introspection

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [propertyNames count]; i++) {
        NSString* propertyName = [propertyNames objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![propertyName isEqualToString:@"DataModel_tag"]) {
            // map (DataModel_tag).propertyName to propertyName
            [mapping mapKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"(DataModel_tag).%@", propertyName]
                toAttribute:propertyName];
        }
    }

    return mapping;
}

+(void)configureMappingProviderForUpload {

    RKObjectMapping* uploadMapping = [Utilities
                                      simpleMappingForObject:[UploadObj class]
                                      withFieldsOrNil:nil];
    // ^ method not shown, but it just maps non-array properties to the object
    // with the same name. This method works in other parts of the code.
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] router]
        routeClass:[UploadObj class]
        toResourcePath:@"/test.php"];

    RKObjectMapping *dataModelMapping = [Utilities mappingForDataModel];

    [uploadMapping mapKeyPath:@"DataModels"
        toRelationship:@"DataModels"
        withMapping:dataModelMapping];

    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider]
        setSerializationMapping:[dataModelMapping inverseMapping]
        forClass:[DataModel class]];

    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider]
        setSerializationMapping:[uploadMapping inverseMapping]
        forClass:[UploadObj class]];   
}
```

When I attempt to map this object, I receive this output for every DataModel attribute:

```
Destination object {
    "<RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE>" = [DataModel_tag value for current instance]
} rejected attribute value [attribute value for current attribute on 
current instance] for keyPath (DataModel_tag).[current attribute name]. 
Skipping...
```

How can I map this object correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry. It was a long time ago.